# window.open() popup is blocked by ad blocker in angular when opening local html from asset folder, working fine if file don't have .html extension

Tags: javascript, angular, types

I am trying to open a separate window using `window.open()` method and using html file from asset folder as an url, but the window is getting blocked by ad blocker. It is working fine if the url don't have .html extension but i don't want to remove it as it is not looking appropriate fix. I have already tried opening opening empty window and then changing its `location.href` and moving `window.open()` in the function which is directly used as click binding in html, but ad blocker isn't letting me do so. Here is the code sample:

````
 const winRef = window.open();
 if (winRef.location.href === 'about:blank') {
    winRef.location.href = url;
 }
 return winRef;
 }```
````

Comment: Is it blocking any specific files or all files? What is the filename you are trying to show? Adblockers try to block files with general names like banner / adtech etc.

Comment: @CodeNinja i just have one html file that i want to show named as popout.html, however i tried with different filenames such as logs.html, op-logs.html etc. but nothing worked

Comment: If there is just one .html file in the folder, why not name it default.html and just give the path to the folder instead of the whole filename. The other option might be to look at the source code of adblocker and see why it's blocked.

Comment: @CodeNinja thanks changing the name of the file worked for me, can we use index.html instead of default.html ?

Comment: Yeah. It should also work.